# Consequences of Goldbach's Conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, big-list, goldbach-type-problems

In a letter of 1742 to Euler, Goldbach expressed the belief that ‘Every integer $N>5$ is the sum of three primes’. Euler replied that this is easily seen to be equivalent to the following statement : ‘Every even integer $2n\geq4$ is the sum of two primes’ . This is what we know as Goldbach's Conjecture.

I am looking for a list/reference which explores the consequences of Goldbach's conjecture. Which problems will be proved?!

Comment: I don't think it is really that Goldbach's conjecture has any interesting applications or consequences; it is more that the conjecture is inherently interesting in its own right. But any new method which solves the Goldbach conjecture would be so groundbreaking it would almost certainly have many more applications. It is not uncommon in analytic number that the methods themselves are of more interest than the applications.

Comment: Note that Goldbach and Euler here are working with a different definition of 'prime' than the modern one; they considered $1$ to be a prime, so that there _is_ actually an equivalence between those two statements. With the modern definition of prime, then every even integer $\gt 2$ being the sum of two primes implies that every odd integer $\gt 5$ is the sum of three primes (add $3$), but the reverse implication is no longer clear.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Are you sure about this? I think the key point in the implication is that in the odd case of Goldbach's original statement, at least one of th e primes must be the only even prime $2$, so all even numbers $>3$ are the sum of two primes, which then implies the odd statement for numbers $>6$ by adding $3$. Whether $1$ is prime or not is immaterial.

Comment: @WillSawin I think you have your parity wrong; for 'all odd integers are the sum of 3 primes' you want _none_ of the primes to be even (unless two of them are). And actually now that I look at it, I'm not sure that 'odd' Goldbach implies Goldbach even if you consider 1 to be a prime; it's possible _a priori_ that some (or many) sufficiently large odd integers are the sum of three primes only if those three primes are large, in which case you can't say anything about even numbers being the sum of two primes.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Goldbach's original statement (at least as quoted in this post) was that *all* integers are the sum of three primes, including both even and odd. For the even integers, one of the primes must be 2, from which you can deduce that the even integers are actually the sums of two primes (and from this statement, you can also deduce the odd case).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki The statement for odd integers alone is also called the "weak Goldbach conjecture" and does not imply the strong one as you stated correctly. Harald Helfgott wrote an article detailing a proof of it. AFAIK it has not been peer-reviewed.

Comment: The same question was asked several years ago on quora. Preda Mihailescu's answer there accords with the comment above by @Daniel. https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-consequences-of-Goldbachs-conjecture There's also a discussion at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266142/goldbach-conjecture-consequences but maybe not very helpful, and with many deleted answers.

Comment: @LorenoHeer: Helfgott's proof will appear in a book published by Princeton University Press. The book is peer reviewed. See https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~harald.helfgott/anglais/book.html

Comment: There’s the famous application to recreational Mathematics: the Sum&Product Puzzle
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_and_Product_Puzzle

Comment: @WillSawin: Your lemma shows “if $2k$ is a sum of three primes, then $2k-2$ is a sum of two primes”.  This implies “if every even number > 4 is a sum of *exactly* three primes, then every even number ≥ 4 is a sum of two primes”, but it does NOT imply “if every even number >4 is a sum of *at most* three primes, then every even number is a sum of two primes”.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine The word "at most" doesn't appear in the quoted statement, so it's at least reasonable to interpret it as "exactly".

Answer (score 9):

Bratus and Pak have [devised an algorithm](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Epak/papers/recfin.pdf) which, given a black box (or "gray box") group $G$ which is known to be isomorphic to $S_n$ or $A_n$, actually explicitly finds such an isomorphism. The algorithm depends on certain quantitative versions of the Goldbach conjecture. They present two versions of the algorithms, one in which $n$ is given, and one in which merely an upper bound for $n$ is given.

Answer (score 5):

Only a partial answer as it is too long for a mere comment. There are known connections between non vanishing of L-functions and some versions of the Goldbach conjecture. Gautami Bhowmik showed that some improvement on the error term for some summatory function of the number of Goldbach decompositions would lead to a tiny strip on the left of the vertical line $\Re(s)=1$ where the Riemann zeta function doesn't vanish.

Similarly, Goldston et al. proved that what they call weak Hardy-Littlewood-Goldbach conjecture would entail that no Landau-Siegel zero exists. There may also be some link between GRH and the upper bound for the quantity I denote by $\alpha_{n}$ in my question About Goldbach's conjecture, but it's hardly legible and I still lack a proper proof.

Answer (score 1):

If the Goldbach's conjecture is true then for every even number $2n$ there exist numbers $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that

$\phi (n_1)+\phi (n_2)=2n$

Where $\phi$ is the $\phi$-Euler function.

Comment: This is obvious, just write $2n+2$ as a sum of two primes.